# I can't make this HTML/CSS Table centered on mobile!? Alignment issue on mobile

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why this code keeps aligning left on mobile, please!? It is fine for desktop but I just can't see why it is aligned to the left on mobile.

TIA :)

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  
  .tg td {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg th {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg .tg-re44 {
    border-color: #000000;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-73oq {
    border-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .tg {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .tg col {
      width: auto !important;
    }
    .tg-wrap {
      overflow-x: auto;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      margin: auto 0px;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="tg-wrap">
  <table class="tg">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-73oq" colspan="4">
          <a href="https://www.quatropi.com/" target="_blank"><img data-file-id="1458450" height="38" src="https://mcusercontent.com/dd416f04f54c1d90160e9bdbe/images/b1d76a57-423d-19c0-a4e2-d51cc6292090.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 127px; height: 38px; margin: 0px;" width="127" /></a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-re44"><a href="https://www.quatropi.com/living-room/" target="_blank">LIVING ROOM</a></td>
        <td class="tg-re44"><a href="https://www.quatropi.com/dining-room/" target="_blank">DINING ROOM</a></td>
        <td class="tg-re44"><a href="https://www.quatropi.com/garden-conservatory/" target="_blank">GARDEN</a></td>
        <td class="tg-re44"><a href="http://quatropi.com/sale/" target="_blank">SALE</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I can tell you, your div is bigger than the screen thus provoking it to overflow on the right. Put a width limit on your main div: `width: 100%`, also make sure the table is never larger than 100%.

However, for a menu, you should consider having a specific mobile menu.

Comment: Can you tell where exactly I would put the width limit please - I am a complete beginner, don't hate me lol